# Use jQuery and ajax to send serialized form as value in data object to php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, serialization

Stripping down this issues, I'd like to send a serialized form string to PHP through AJAX in the data object. My form is:

```
<form id="add_project_form" method="post">
    <div class="form_group">
        <p>Title:</p>
        <input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form_group form_select" id="visible">
        <p>Visible: 
            <select name="visible">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>0</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit_project">Add Project</a>
</form>
```

I can do it like data: $('form').serialize() but cant seem to pass it in an object.

```
$('#submit_project').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_calls.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            add_project_call: true,
            form_data: $('#add_project_form').serialize()
        },
        success: function(addedResults) {
            console.log(addedResults);
        }
    });
});
```

and, just to test, get back the title from PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['add_project_call'])) {
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $visible = $_POST['visible'];
   echo $title;
}
```

I see that serialize turns the form data into a string, but how can I access the values in PHP?

Thanks,

Comment: What does `$_POST` in PHP contain when you submit the form?

Comment: I get a notice about the indexes being undefined.

Comment: Yes, you would probably see why if you did what I asked, I guess you'd see your mistake then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change javascript like:

```
$('#submit_project').click(function() {
    var form_data = {};
    $('#add_project_form').serializeArray().map(function(n){form_data[n.name] = n.value;});
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_calls.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            add_project_call: true,
            form_data: form_data
        },
        success: function(addedResults) {
            console.log(addedResults);
        }
    });
});
```

change php file (ajax_calls.php) like:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_project_call'])) {
   $title = $_POST['form_data']['title'];
   $visible = $_POST['form_data']['visible'];
   echo $title;
}
```